# Выделение всей строки узла TreeView в WF C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

В общем, имею *TreeView* дерево узлов с подзулами. Проблема в том, что красится лишь только текст, а мне нужно покрасить всю строку (как на скрине ниже).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, я выбираю узел *TreeView* и у меня **вся строка** красится в синий цвет. Я выбираю подузел и строка красится в желтый цвет. У самого *TreeView* же **без выделений** должны быть узлы закрашены в разные цвета (как на правой части рисунка (где надпись ПОСЛЕ)).
Возможно ли это реализовать без "самотворчества"? Если нет, то что можно придумать?

p.s.: про `treeView1.ShowLines = false; treeView1.FullRowSelect=true;` знаю, это немножко не то. В этом случае пропадают линии иерархии слева от дерева.

**Заранее, всем спасибо за помощь!**

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1213466/WPF-TreeGrid-using-a-DataGrid

Comment: @tym32167, а разве WPF и WF не разные вещи? Хотя идея неплохая )

Comment: В принципе никто не запрещает юзать впф контролы в винформах, но я да, пропустил ваши теги.

Comment: Либо отрисовывать вручную (самотворчество), либо поискать готовый подходящий контрол (всякие там telerik, devexpress).